# Compare a date in a cell against a date range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'd like to compare a date in cell E11 with a date range in E2:E10. Here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytRQF.png) of the worksheet I'm working on.

If the date in E11 is earlier than all of the dates in the range, I'd like it to return the following text: "Date E11 is earlier than the range".
If the date is later than all, then: "Date E11 is later than the range".

Could someone assist with creating the script?

Comment: Welcome! To best "help us help you", please consider sharing your file (or a copy with some anonymized placeholder data). Make sure it's shared as "Anyone with the link can Edit." Not sure how? Here's Google's [help topic](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2494822) or check out this quick [video](https://youtu.be/y7fiYarBHh4) of the steps. Most important; please manually add examples of the output values you want it to show automatically, and mark them to say that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function isLastGreaterThanTheRest() {
  var result='Yes';
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getRange('E2:E11');
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length-1;i++) {
    if(new Date(vA[vA.length-1][0]).valueOf() < new Date(vA[i][0])) {
      result='No';
      break;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```